# how to avoid using ifdef to make code more testable

Tags: c++

I am creating a log file for logging information. It has a switch to turn it on or off.

```
#define LOG_FILE

#ifdef LOG_FILE
    #define LOG(MESSAGE1, MESSAGE2) log(MESSAGE1, MESSAGE2);
#else
    #define LOG(MESSAGE1, MESSAGE2)
#endif
```

Now I can control logging using LOG_FILE switch. I was wondering there are any other way achieve similar feature which is more testable?

Comment: I suppose you cannot have both lines compiled into the same unit so `ifdef` seems like the best choice. For tests, you can of course define LOG_FILE on the command line while compiling, so you can also automate this for tests.

Comment: What are your criteria for "more testable"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use templates like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#define USE_LOGGING true

template<bool>
inline void log(const std::string& message, const std::string&  verbosity) {}

template<>
inline void log<true>(const std::string& message, const std::string& verbosity) {
    std::cout << verbosity << ": " << message << "\n";
}

constexpr auto logMessage = log<USE_LOGGING>;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    logMessage("Test", "Warning");
}
```

By this you will have both versions available, using logMessage gives you the global settings, alternatively you can use log directly which is a local definition of how to use logging.

Comment: In some cases it is better to add `inline` to be sure that function call is removed. And to use `string_view` or to pass `const std::string&`

Comment: @DmitrySazonov `inline` only tells that the function may be defined in several translation units and this does not violate ODR, thus enabling to put the function definition in a header. Compilers usually ignore `inline` for the matter of optimizing function calls, and do the optimization if they think it's worth it (even without the `inline` keyword). Also, templates are by definition inline.

Comment: Would you recommend adding noexcept?

Comment: @lisyarus thats why I wrote "in some cases". Usually it is not necessary, when template functions are defined in .h files.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov You wrote "to be sure that function call is removed", which is not the case why `inline` may be needed nowadays. And, as I've said, templates are automatically inline.

Comment: It does not harm anyone so I'll keep it, thanks for the input though

Comment: @MarcoDennstädt You can add `noexcept` to the first version of `log`, since it does nothing. The second version that outputs something to `std::cout` may throw, and you should not in any case mark it with `noexcept`.